# Ubuntu Studio does not start with XFCE desktop but the other one. How to fix?

Tags: 14.04, xfce, login-screen, desktop-environments

I have installed ubuntu studio 14.04 and when I changed desktop from the login screen it can't change back to xfce. I select xfce but it logs me in the other desktop environment. Any ideas why that happens and how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Just slide up/down users and button goes to active? and you can choose a session

Comment: No matter which session I chose, it logs with ubuntustudio session, not xfce4 session. Maybe if I clear session files?